# TypeError: Cannot read property 'temp' of undefined in Angular 2+ while passing data into canvas graph

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, canvas, angular5

Hello Guys I'm new to Angular 2+,

I have data from my API formatted like this:

```json
{
  "temp":49.47,
  "time":"05:17:55 PM"
}
```

Which I need to take the data from above format and pass the data into graph.

I'm able to get a data from Api but I fail in passing data in Component File, Can anyone check my code and Help me out?

I have a ServerService which is grab the data from my API

```js
@Injectable()
export class ServerService {
    private basicUrl ='http://10.188.16.104:8001/ws/temp';
dataSource;

    constructor(private http: Http) { } 

  getServers(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.basicUrl)
.subscribe(data =>this.dataSource =data);
    }
}
```

From my component code :

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerService } from '../server.service';
//import { Http } from '@angular/http';
//import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx'; 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ledswitch',
  templateUrl: './ledswitch.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ledswitch.component.css']
})
export class LedswitchComponent implements OnInit {

  dataSourceObservable :Observable<any>
  dataSource;

  constructor(private serverService: ServerService) {
           console.log("My Data"+this.dataSource);
           console.log("My Data");
           this.dataSource  = this.serverService.getServers()
     .map(response => response.json());

   }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

// Chart
  chartOptions = {
    responsive: true
  };

// Passing X-axis data in a graph
  chartData = [
    { data: [this.dataSource.temp], label: 'Temp vs Time' },
  ];
// Passing Y-axis data in a graph
  chartLabels = [this.dataSource.time];

    this.chartLabels = [...this.chartLabels, label];

  }

  onChartClick(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }

}
```

and HTML code is

```
 <div style="width: 50%;">
    <canvas
        baseChart
        [chartType]="'line'"
        [datasets]="chartData"
        [labels]="chartLabels"
        [options]="chartOptions"
        [legend]="true"
        (chartClick)="onChartClick($event)">
    </canvas>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your service should return the observable:

```
@Injectable()
export class ServerService {
    private basicUrl ='http://10.188.16.104:8001/ws/temp';
dataSource;

    constructor(private http: Http) { } 

  getServers(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.basicUrl).map(response => response.json());
    }
}
```

Then in your component:

```
  constructor(private serverService: ServerService) {}


 ngOnInit() {
     // Chart
     this.chartOptions = {
         responsive: true
     };

     this.serverService.getServers()
         .subscribe(data => {
             // Passing X-axis data in a graph
             this.chartData = [{
                 data: [data.temp],
                 label: 'Temp vs Time'
             }, ];
             // Passing Y-axis data in a graph
             this.chartLabels = [data.time];

             this.chartLabels = [...this.chartLabels, label];

         });
 }
```

Comment: ERROR in src/app/ledswitch/ledswitch.component.ts(41,31): error TS2339: Property 'temp' does not exist on type 'Response'.
src/app/ledswitch/ledswitch.component.ts(45,40): error TS2339: Property 'time' does not exist on type 'Response'.

Comment: and it's Compiled successfully.

Comment: Well check your response dude. I don't have access to your application. What does the server returns? Can't you even do that?